# Enable button if the component values have been changed in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to enable my react form, if the form values are different from the initial props values. My form is loaded through props and if the current state is different from props, I want to enable the button. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **flag** in your state like `isEdited` and have a handler to set this flag like

```
onEditHandler = () =>{
  setState((previousState, currentProps) => {
      if(this.state !== currentProps){
         return {isEdited:true};
      }else{
         return {isEdited:false};
      } 
  });
}
```

call this handler in `onChange()` handler of your inputs.

> Use this **flag** in your button to **enable** and **disable** it

```
<button disable={this.state.isEdited}></button>
```